# How to show Google Play stores window as overlay on top of C# android application

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I am developing a C# application for android where I want to show the Google Play Store window as an overlay on top of my application (my application should not go to background). How can I do it? We can also do it in Java.

I have attached a video what i want to do.

Otherwise you can do it yourself by clicking on an admob interstitial ad on Android mobile, and if its a play store app whose ad is being shown, it wil open a small window at bottom of the mobile without leaving my application. I want to achieve the same

I assume this has tobe some kind of Admob method or an API and not some custom window because if u click install on that same window it directly install that application without prompting that install from other sources. which is the case if you try to install an app from a source other then app store itself.

In C# I have tried to do it by opening it from android market. i.e

```
Application.OpenURL ("market://details?q=pname:com.mycopmany.myapp/");
```

In Java I have tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "market://details?q=pname:com.mycopmany.myapp");

startActivity(intent);

 

// or search for a term

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "market://search?q=some+search+query");

startActivity(intent);
```